# What do these lines mean in Ivor Gurney's "Laventie"?

Tags: meaning, poetry, ivor-gurney

Could you please help me understand the meaning of a poem by Ivor Gurney, an Englishman who fought in the First World War.

From his "[Laventie](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/57254/laventie)":

> Of Maconachie, Paxton, Tickler, and Gloucester’s Stephens;
> Fray Bentos, Spiller and Baker, odds and evens
> Of trench food, but the everlasting clean craving
> For bread, the pure thing, blessed beyond saving.

I highly appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Maconachie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maconochie#:%7E:text=Maconochie%20was%20a%20stew%20of,trenches%20during%20World%20War%20I.) was a tinned stew named after the company which made it; [T G Tickler](http://www.tommyspackfillers.com/showitem.asp?itemRef=RL555) was a Lincolnshire company who made tins of jam and marmalade, [Fray Bentos](https://www.theguardian.com/travel/2018/jul/08/fray-bentos-uruguay-not-just-a-meat-pie) was and is a brand of tinned ("corned" or "bully") beef named after the Uruguayan town where it was originally produced; [Spillers and Baker's](https://glamarchives.gov.uk/2018/01/26/spillers-bakers-ltd-cardiff/) was a big, British milling company originally from Bridgewater but then with a large mill in Cardiff which is now luxury flats.

All those names were industrial food producers, I can't find any reference to Paxton's or Stephens (although Gurney was once a chorister in [Gloucester cathedral](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-gloucestershire-26800146?print=true)) but from the context it would seem that they were large suppliers of tinned or otherwise preserved and packed food to the army.

I suppose that there may be a connection to Spillers dog biscuits and Baker's Complete tinned dog food but I don't really know!

Comment: Excellent, concise answer!

Comment: Dear BoldBen Thank you for your kind and precise answer. I still can't understand the latter part, "Of trench food, but the everlasting
clean craving For bread, the pure thing, blessed beyond saving"  Does the soldier want bread but can't get one and bemoans for the lack of bread?

Comment: I don't know what kind of bread they had in the trenches, but no doubt it would be something that would keep a long time, nothing like what we know as 'freshly-baked bread'.

Comment: @KateBunting There are images on the net of bread being baked during WW1, at least by Germans and Australians, but I suspect that it never made it to the front lines because of the transport difficulties. This would mean that the front line soldiers only had a chance of eating it on their rotations to the rear (I think they rotated every two weeks normally). However I suspect that unappetising alternatives like [Huntley and Palmers No 4](https://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/30081986) were much more commonly available even behind the lines (except for the headquarters of course)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed advise,and sorry for my late reply. Your comments help me a lot.

Comment: @Suzie8 Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange! You've created a second account. To link your accounts together, see [this help page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Then the system will recognize you as the original poster of the question, and you can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark under the voting arrows. (Acceptance means the question has been satisfactorily solved). We aren't a traditional forum and all answers are expected to be answers; if an answer solves your problem the proper thing to do is accept it, not post an answer in reply.